Retrieving OUTPUT values from a table variable using Dapper
I have a SQL Proc which uses a MERGE statement to INSERT when not matched and the OUTPUT values are  stored in a table variable
  INSERT
            (
                [Code],
                [BenchmarkCode],
                [ExternalCode],
                [DefinitionId]
            )           
            VALUES
            (
               Source.Code, Source.BenchmarkCode, Source.ExternalCode, Source.DefinitionId
            )
            OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.DefinitionId, inserted.PortfolioCode, inserted.BenchmarkCode, inserted.ExternalCode 
INTO @inserted_values

How do I get the values from @inserted_values using DAPPER, IDbAdapter

It appears like execute and query is not combined on Dapper. Is it viable approach where I could wrap the dbAdapter.ExecuteAsync followed by the query from the table varaible with dbAdapter.QueryAsync("SELECT Code, BenchmarkCode, ExternalCode, DefinitionId from @inserted_values");

https://www.learndapper.com/stored-procedures can be help

INTO @inserted_value why is that there? Or just do SELECT * FROM @inserted_value; afterwards.
